# Puppet agent test is failing

Tags: puppet

I am executing puppet agent test with "no op". I just want to see what are all changes it will do ( without actually doing anything ).
When I am executing the command it is throwing below error.

```
[root@hi01 ~]# puppet agent -t --noop

err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed when searching for node hi01.company.com: Could not load external node results for db20.viwii.pvt: key is a Fixnum, not a string or symbol
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

I tried to execute this in debug mode and here is the output of the same:

```
    [root@hi01 ~]# puppet agent -t --noop --debug

debug: Failed to load library 'selinux' for feature 'selinux'

debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file roleadd does not exist

debug: Failed to load library 'ldap' for feature 'ldap'

debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: feature ldap is missing

debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist

debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/log]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/run]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/hi01.company.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys/hi01.company.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys/hi01.company.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/crl.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/client_data]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/classes.txt]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/resources.txt]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]

debug: Finishing transaction 16235740

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/log]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/run]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/hi01.company.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys/hi01.company.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys/hi01.company.com.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]

debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/crl.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]

debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]

debug: Finishing transaction 15391060

debug: Using cached certificate for ca

debug: Using cached certificate for hi01.company.com

debug: Finishing transaction 14823520

debug: Loaded state in 0.23 seconds

debug: catalog supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml dot pson raw yaml; using pson

debug: Using cached certificate for ca

debug: Using cached certificate for hi01.company.com

debug: Using cached certificate_revocation_list for ca

err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed when searching for node hi01.company.com: Could not load external node results for hi01.company.com: key is a Fixnum, not a string or symbol

warning: Not using cache on failed catalog

err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

debug: report supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml pson raw yaml; using pson
```

Any idea?

Comment: looks to me like an issue with your `ENC`

Comment: The error appears to be on your master (probably with your ENC). What do the puppet master logs look like?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Guys. The issue stands resolved.
So I am using mongo to store node object and somehow the record for this particular server was messed up, once I deleted and recreated the record it started working fine.